# Is it theoretically possible to get a fermion fields from compactifying a bosonic field theory?

Tags: representation-theory, fermions, spinors, bosons, compactification

It doesn't seem impossible to me that compactifying a purely bosonic field theory could result in spinor fields.

For example, the spin groups (the double covers of $O(n)$) have representations in $2^{n/2}$ dimensions. So a bosonic theory with $2^{n/2}$ dimensions has enough degrees of freedom to represent fermion particles of $n$ dimensions.

Certainly in 2 dimensions there is the process of "bozonisation" which blurs the line between fermions and bosons.

For a given high dimension with space time symmetry $O(d,1)$ it should be large enough to contain the symmetries of a spin group, the symmetries of a fermion field. And hence by restricting the other symmetries in some way (perhaps by compactification) the remaining components of the fields should have fermionic character.

Is this argument correct?

I don't think a simple compactification would work, however. It would have to be some strange construction. Since the Spin representation is in $2^{d/2}$ dimensions whereas the fermions travel in $d$ dimensions. Also the double-cover needs to be reduced to a single-cover.

Rotating a fermion by $2\pi$ should not bring it back to itself, and this would be encoded somehow in a position in the compact dimensions.

So, is this at all theoretically possible? And if so, what kind of compactification would this involve?

Answer (score 2):

Since "bosonic" and "fermionic" are not duality invariant properties of a field theory, as you point out, it is conceivable that you'd be able to combine compactification with a higher dimensional version of bosonization in order to see fermions emerge as you go to a smaller dimension.

But arriving at such a phenomenon using only kinematics doesn't sound possible. When decomposing representations of $\mathfrak{so}(d)$ to those of $\mathfrak{so}(d-1)$, tensors go to tensors.

**Edit**

There are [some](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.5344) [examples](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.01617) where the opposite happens. I.e. a CFT with fermions becoming bosonic when you dimensionally reduce in the proper way.